# Change action in form with dom script

Tags: javascript, html

How can I change the `onSubmit` value dynamic or should I remove `onSubmit` and have `<action="return zomlink();">`

What I want is to change the `action/onsubmit` link to a new link depending on what option they select in the drop down box. I cannot use `Jquery` i need it in plain `javascript` form.

```
   <form method="post" id="buyvipform" name="buyvipform" class="buyvipform" onSubmit="return zomlink();">

<select name="zomlink" id="zomlink" style="margin-top: 290px;">
<option value="1906083">3 days Trial (2€)</option>
<option value="1906104">31 days (19€)</option>
<option value="1906125">90 days (50€)</option>
<option value="1906146">365 days (99€)</option>
</select>


<input type="submit" value="" style="background:url(<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/vbestall.png) no-repeat; width: 106px; height: 40px; border: 0px;">
<input type="hidden" name="hide_credits" value="True">

</form>
```

Script:

```
function zomlink() {
  if(document.zomlink.value == '1906104') {
    document.buyvipform.action = 'http://google.com';
  }
     if(document.zomlink.value == '1906125') {
    document.buyvipform.action = 'http://facebook.com';
  }

  return true;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6x4u28yd/

Comment: you mean for example if someone chose a different option Form submit in different page???

Comment: Hey, it should change the form action link or in this case the form onSubmit value to another value. So the form get submitted to the right link.

Comment: I'm posting a comment since I'm not sure why would you use a submit button in this case. However, check this snippet http://jsbin.com/foyanasitici/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Here is a non-jQuery solution.

```
<form method="get" id="buyvipform" name="buyvipform" class="buyvipform">

<select name="zomlink" id="zomlink" style="margin-top: 290px;">
    <option value="1906083">3 days Trial (2€)</option>
    <option value="1906104">31 days (19€)</option>
    <option value="1906125">90 days (50€)</option>
    <option value="1906146">365 days (99€)</option>
</select>

<input type="hidden" name="hide_credits" value="True">

</form>

<button onclick="zomlink()">Submit</button>


<script>

function zomlink() {

    var myForm = document.forms["buyvipform"];

    if(document.getElementById("zomlink").value == '1906104') myForm.action = 'http://google.com';
    else if(document.getElementById("zomlink").value == '1906125') myForm.action = 'http://facebook.com';

    document.getElementById("buyvipform").submit();

}
</script>
```

Comment: Did you read the question? "I cannot use Jquery i need it in plain javascript form"

Comment: @LcSalazar my apologies. I have removed the jQuery from the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `submit` input, set your input as `type=button`, and add a `onclick=""` event to it, checking the condition you wanted.

Then, call the `.submit();` method from the form DOM element.

```
<form method="post" id="buyvipform" name="buyvipform" class="buyvipform">

    <select name="zomlink" id="zomlink" style="margin-top: 290px;">
        <option value="1906083">3 days Trial (2€)</option>
        <option value="1906104">31 days (19€)</option>
        <option value="1906125">90 days (50€)</option>
        <option value="1906146">365 days (99€)</option>
    </select>


    <input type="button" onclick="zomlink();" value="Submit" style="background:url(<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/vbestall.png) no-repeat; width: 106px; height: 40px; border: 0px;" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hide_credits" value="True" />

</form>
```

JS:

```
function zomlink() {
    var form = document.getElementById("buyvipform");
    var select= document.getElementById("zomlink");

    if(select.value == '1906104') {
        form.action = 'http://google.com';
    }
     if(select.value == '1906125') {
        form.action = 'http://facebook.com';
    }

    form.submit();
}
```